# Dataflow is failing when the File Path is provided with more than one directory level

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a dataflow in ADF and in the File Path variable of the dataset, i am passing the directory structure where my input files are present over Azure containers.

When this directory structure comprises of only one level(For Eg: source ), then everything works fine. But when this directory structure has more than one value(For Eg: source/database_files) then i start getting error. Below is the error that i receive:
{"message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'input': abfss://source/database_files@stgresourcedfs.core.windows.net/ has invalid authority

Answer (score 0):

Here I repro'd to pass multilevel directory by the parameterization.

Create linked service and dataset with the parameter.
[image]

[image]

Provide file path dynamically from the dataset parameters.

**In the Container path it cannot accept `'/'` so we need to parameterize the path.**
[image]

We are able to preview data of the dataset.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am using the dataflow within an ADF pipeline. So i am using the parameterization. In my scenario, i am passing the parameters from the ADF pipeline and getting the error. So even after parameterization i got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit a similar issue myself.   This is correct syntax...

```
FileSource = <blob reference>    Directory = concat(<Path>, <filename>)
```

This is not allowed:

```
FileSource = concat( <blob>,<Path>)     Directory = <filename>
```

They sound as though they are going to be similar but a FileSource has to definitively be a blob reference or an equivalent 'thing' for other data sources.  i.e. the source has to be some kind of recognised object.  So you can't add a path in that box but you can add it in the Directory.

The issue is then nothing to do with permissions.  It's failure to access the object with the path appended because there is no such object.

Hope that helps ;)